# Why parseInt does not ignore first symbol, or character of an integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to change a string value to integer in jQuery. Is there a workaround of having `parseInt` disregard the symbol $ and rather capture the integer/number 90.00?

```
var price =("$90.00");
var i = (price);
var j = parseInt(i);
console.log(j)
```

expecting an output of : 90.00

```
output NAN
```

Comment: What would you do with `$45.49`?

Comment: To @Kosh's point, aren't you better off using `parseFloat` in this context? (this is not related to your issue but good to consider)

Comment: what is ??? var i = $(price); why u selecting 90.00 as selector ??

Answer (score 2):

If you [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) you will see that:

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Since `$` is not a valid numerical character - parseInt will ignore it and all the following characters, and you will actually have `parseInt` on empty string - `parseInt('')`, which results in NaN.

```js
console.log(parseInt(''));
```

If you know that your strings contains only the dollar-sign and you want to remove it you can use the `replace` function to do that:

```js
const price = "$90.0";
console.log(parseInt(price.replace(/\$/, '')));
```

Comment: In my case I am getting an output of NAN and that's not what I want. I am Expecting an output of 90.00. How to work around it? @Dekel

Comment: This `replace` solution is the way to go, and can probably be improved further to remove any initial characters that aren't a number, so that a whitespace followed by a `£` sign would also be removed, and maybe use `parseFloat`… depending on OP's needs, that is!

Comment: @appdesigns if you want `90.00` this is not parseInt - you can try the `parseFloat` based on my example.

Comment: getting an error:    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>   @Dekel

Comment: `replace` is a method that belongs to the string, no to the InputElement. You should get the value out of that element.